# Cómo asociar pares de elementos de dos listas

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for

Tengo dos listas:

Lista n:

```py
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Lista inputList:

```py
[4, 83, 91, 6, 21, 64, 12, 24, 17, 91]
```

y quiero devolver el resultado de sumar los elementos de "inputLista" que en su misma posición en la lista "n" sean 0 e ídem para los 1.

Ésto es lo que llevo y me sigue fallando:

```py
def fitness_w_carritos(n):
   carro_0=0
   carro_1=0
   for i in range(0, len(n)-1):
       for j in range(0, len(inputList)):
           if i==0:
               carro_0+=inputList[i]
           else:
               carro_1+=inputList[i]

   return carro_1
```

El return puede ser opcional, es decir, puedes devolver carro_0 como carro_1, es simplemente saber que lo que hace el método funciona bien.

Por lo tanto si lo que quieres es devolver carro_0, debería ser 6+21+64+12+24+91= 218
mientras al invocar a carro_1, debería devolver 4+83+91+17= 195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n=[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
inputList=[4, 83, 91, 6, 21, 64, 12, 24, 17, 91]

def fitness_w_carritos(n):
    carro_0=0
    carro_1=0

    for i in range(0, len(n)):
       if n[i]==1:
           carro_1+=inputList[i]
       else:
           carro_0+=inputList[i]
    print(carro_0)
    print(carro_1)
```

Realmente, no necesitas dos bucles, te basta con uno que recorra `inputList` y que compare la posición que esta iterando con la misma posición de la otra lista n, de forma que si es 0 lo sume a `carro_0` y si es 1, lo sume a `carro_1`.